# Scheme using input parameter in inner function

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, let

I'm new to Scheme and to functional programming in general.

As part of an exercise, I try to implement a function that that takes a number `n` and prints line by line first `n` Fibonacci numbers

The problem is that when the program reaches the recursive call, it doesn't recognize `n` and so I get contract violation error.

From exploring the web I think I need to use `let` function in some way but I'm not sure how.

Here's the code:

```
(define fibo (lambda (n)
           (if (= n 1)
                 1
                 (if (= n 2)
                   (begin
                     (display "1")
                     (newline)
                     1)
                   (begin
                     (display
                      (+ (fibo (- n 1)) (fibo (- n 2))))
                     )))))
```

And the error I get is:

```
contract violation
expected: number?
  given: #<void>
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the error is the fact that `fibo` is supposed to be a function that returns an integer, while in the second case of the inner `if` you simply print a value (and `display` returns `#<void>`, which is not an integer).

This is immediately clear if you indent properly your code:

```
(define fibo
  (lambda (n)
    (if (= n 1)
        1
        (if (= n 2)
            (begin
              (display "1")
              (newline)
              1)
            (begin
              (display (+ (fibo (- n 1)) (fibo (- n 2)))))))))
```

You can note that the first branch of the second `if` terminates with `1`, which is returned, while the second branch returns the result of the `display`.

If you remove the various `display` calls (which are not useful since the values printed contains many repetitions), the function produces the correct result:

```
(define fibo
  (lambda (n)
    (if (= n 1)
        1
        (if (= n 2)
            1
            (+ (fibo (- n 1)) (fibo (- n 2)))))))
```

Note that it can be rewritten in a more concise form:

```
(define fibo
  (lambda (n)
    (if (<= n 2)
        1
        (+ (fibo (- n 1)) (fibo (- n 2))))))
```

Finally, if you want to display all the numbers of Fibonacci until a certain value, you could define a function like:

```
(define display-all-fibo
  (lambda (n)
    (define display-fibo
      (lambda (i)
        (if (<= i n)
            (begin
              (display (fibo i))
              (newline)
              (display-fibo (+ i 1)))
            (display "Done!"))))
    (display-fibo 1)))

(display-all-fibo 9)

1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
Done!
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer but I'm not allowed to use `when` statement ... Is there some other way of doing it?

Comment: I changed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Split the problem up. Separate dirty side effects from the function that generates the numbers:

```
(define (fib-list from to)
  ...)
(fib-list 10 20)
; ==> (55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181 6765)
```

Then it's easy to make a function that prints said list:

```
(define (print-fib-list from to)
  (for-each displayln (fib-list from to)))
```

This uses `for-each` but it's pretty much just as easy doing it with recursion.